# Obter dados via JSON por URL em C#

Tags: c#, json

Estou precisando obter dados via JSON, através de uma URL, este link: https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/egx/

Estou tentando com o código abaixo, mas já recebo erro assim que ele faz o download da string.

O erro recebido é:

> A cadeira de caracteres não está no formato JSON.

Porém, pelo (pouco) que entendo, me parece que o retorno está OK no formato.

Alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Este é meu código:

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/EGX/");

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            var btc = 0.0;


                foreach (var result in obj.BTC_EGX)

                btc = result.last;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá! houve uma atualização no protocolo TLS para o 1.2 com isso chamadas https deixaram de funcionar por estarem setadas ao antigo TLS 1.0. Seta o Secutiry Protocol do System.Net conforme adicionei no seu exemplo abaixo. abs

```
using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/EGX/");

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            var btc = 0.0;


            foreach (var result in obj.BTC_EGX)

                btc = result.last;

        }
```

Comment: Oi Paulrocost, deu erro ao compilar: 
Erro  O nome 'ServicePointManager' não existe no contexto atual

Comment: amanhã retomo pra tentar resolver isso aqui, de qualquer maneira, obrigado pela força!

Comment: você só precisa adicionar a referencia, o `using`, para o `ServicePoint Manager`. Se não me engano é: `using System.Net;`.

Comment: Isso mesmo; precisa adicionar a referencia "using System.Net" pois o objeto que você irá setar o tls está dentro dela.

Comment: Perfeito Resolveu o problema! Muito obrigado @paulocost e vhoyer